# Dealing with a large kernel matrix in SVM

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, classification, svm

I have a matrix `X`, size *40*-by-*60000*

while writing the SVM, I need to form a linear kernel: `K = X'*X`

And of course I would get an error

```
Requested 60000x60000 (26.8GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference.
```

How is it usually done? The data set is `Mnist`, so someone must have done this before. In this case `rank(K) <= 40`, I need a way to store `K` and later pass it to `quadprog`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that unlike math.SE SO does not support TeX, as you have noticed, so I changed the mathematics to code formatting.

Comment: You could convert the data to singles. Matlab stores data as double (takes 8 bytes per number). x=single(x) converts it to 4 bytes per number, but you would still need 13.4 GB.

Answer (score 2):

> How is it usually done?

Usually kernel matrices for big datasets are **not** precomputed. Since optimisation methods used (like SMO or gradient descent) do only need access to a subset of samples in each iteration, you simply need a data structure which is a lazy kernel matrix, in other words - each time an optimiser requests K[i,j] you literally compute K(xi,xj) then. Often, there are also caching mechanisms to make sure that often requested kernel values are already prepared etc.

Comment: Oh my, can `quadprog` accept input that is a kernel function? (kernel function k generates Gram matrix K: k(xi,xj) = K(xi,xj). )

Comment: quadrprog does not, and this is not what people use for SVMs.

Comment: Hi, is there any simple optimization addon in Matlab that can deal with large Kernel in the manner you described? the reason I can't use libsvm is because I have no C/C++ compiler in my Matlab, and I can't install it either...

Comment: Hi, please see my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565478/primal-svm-matlab-quadprog-issue

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to commit to a linear kernel (or any other kernel whose corresponding feature transformation is easily computed) you can avoid allocating O(N^2) memory by using a **primal** optimization method, which does not construct the full kernel matrix K.

Primal methods represent the model using a weighted sum of the training samples' features, and so will only take O(NxD) memory, where N and D are the number of training samples and their feature dimension.

You could also use [liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) (if you resolve the C++ issues).
Note this comment from their website: "Without using kernels, one can quickly train a much larger set via a linear classifier."

Comment: I like this answer, indeed Primal SVM with soft margin is what I tried. Though I have a different problem :(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565478/primal-svm-matlab-quadprog-issue

Answer (score -3):

This problem occurs due to the large size of your data set, thus it exceeds the amount of RAM available in your system. In 64-bit systems data processing performs better than in 32-bit, so you'll want to check which of the two your system is.

Comment: On 64-bit you have more RAM availible. 32-bit limits you to 2^32 (=4,294,967,296) memory positions. So max 4GB. On 64-bit you can access more.

Comment: @rezafakhriyan if you think this answer holds no merit now, you can either [edit] it to be correct, or delete it altogether by pressing the "delete" button on the lower left of the post. There's no obligation to do either, but do note that subsequent downvoted answers can result in an answer ban, so editing the answer into shape is preferred.